# Shipping Method is hide if Estimate Shipping and Tax values are empty

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods

**Problem** : Shipping methods are display already in cart page. But I did not want that.

**What I want** : I want that when cart page is load, any shipping method must not be load.  after the page load i select Estimate Shipping and Tax then after shipping methods will be loaded according to State and Zip/Postal Code.

Any one know **first** how to hide all shiping methods and **second** how to display appropriate or suitable shipping method on cart page after select Estimate Shipping and Tax ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.